# No operator "==" matches these operands string

Tags: c++

I have a problem with this code, I'm trying to verify if a letter is in a word, but for some reasons it won't allow me to put `==`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

bool Verification(string a, string b)
{
    bool VF = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == b) //Here is the problem
        {
            VF = true;
        }

    }
    return VF;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean? `if (a[i] == b[i])`

Comment: As the error says, there is no `operator==` that can compare a `char` and a `string`

Comment: Why would I put that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is a string and `b` is a string.
`a[i]` is a `char`. You compare `char` to `string` - obviously, it will not work.

If you want to check if a **letter** (i.e. `char`) exists in a **sentence** (i.e. `string`), you can implement the function this way:

```
bool Verification(string a, char b) // <-- notice: b is char
{
    bool VF = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == b) 
        {
            VF = true;
        }
    }
    return VF;
}    

// Usage:
Verification("abc", 'a'); // <-- notice: quotes are double for string and single for char
```

Actually, there is a method **[`string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)**, which can help you to find an occurence of `string` or `char` in another `string`
You can replace your code with:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

bool Verification(string a, char b)
{
    return a.find(b) != string::npos;
}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. But how did my a string became a char when i had [i]?

Comment: @JonathanBouchard In any language (f.i., in English) **word** consists of **letters**. So, in C++ and many other languages **string** consists of **char**s. [`string::operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/), which you have applied, returns **char**. If you have a **word (string)** **apple**, then the 5-th **letter (char)** is `e`.

Comment: @JonathanBouchard Please, check my updated answer. I have read your question carefully and have updated the answer to comply with your requirements.